# How to compare to RDD[(Int,Int)] maps?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am implementing *k-means* with Spark on my own as an exercise.
To do this, I need to compare 2 maps of `id -> cluster_id` on each step. Currently I do it by collecting both of them and comparing as two plain scala Maps.

Is there a way to do this in parallel? Is it worth it?

**UPDATE:**

Let me describe the situation in details, starting with K-MEANS Clustering algorithim(it's simple)

1. pick random K points from all N point making them centroids.
2. assign each point to closest centroid(according to Eucledean distance)
3. recalclulate centroids, grouping all points by assigned centroids, caclulating average of those
4. **repeat step 2-3 if recalculation generated a mapping (obj_id -> centroid_id) other then the one on previous step**

The step #4 is a problem. I need to compare mapping I had on the previous step with the one I have now, and this should be somehow done in parallel without too much random reads across the workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about what do you mean by "comparing" them. The answer to your question really depends on that! If you could provide more detail, I'll edit my answer accordingly, but a generic question can only yield a generic answer ^_^

If you just need to test equality it's pretty straightforward (and order independent, as expected by a map):

```
val x = Map[Int, Int](1->2, 2->3)
val y = Map[Int, Int](2->3, 1->2)
(x == y) == true
```

If you only want to test that they have the same key-sets but different mappings (maybe because you want to test the termination of an update step) you can compare the keys directly either as iterators or sets

```
(x.keys == y.keySet) == true
```

If your problem arises from the fact that your maps are too big and you want to make the equality test in parallel, things become tricky: you can do a split of the pairs according to the keys and have parallel check on every slice: if all your checks are positive, then you have equality.
You can do this either by splitting x AND y in slices according to the key value/hash and send to different actors (if you are using actors, for example), or just iterating over x and checking on a different actor the value of y for that key.

In both cases, I think this only makes sense if either a) your two maps are not in the same process' memory, and therefore accessing them is slow and blocking, b) your comparison is not just value-equality but it requires some intense computation that can benefit from async pipelining.

Note that I have replied under the assumption that you are using basic, generic maps structures. If you have some performance constraints, you may want to implement your own map structure tailored for your specific needs, even tough it's unlikely to imagine a scenario where the library versions will not be optimized enough to do better than your own.

**EDIT**
Given the new info, my answer is still pretty unchanged. Just split the entries in x in n slices assigned by hash of the key and check if y contains them with the same value.

Comment: I added some details to the question.